# Add custom css class to WordPress Gallery

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I would like to add a custom css class to the native WordPress gallery. For example, this one outputs the following HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-2" class="gallery galleryid-1715 gallery-columns-4 gallery-size-thumbnail">
```

I'd like to just add in a custom class of `iwmp`.

What's the best way of doing this? I was hoping for a non JS solution. Thanks

EDIT: Answered my question below.

Comment: Why not adding the `iwmp` class properties into `gallery`?

Answer (score 1):

This link solved my problem: http://www.sk23.co.uk/wordpress/how-to-override-the-default-wordpress-gallery-embedded-css-styles-in-wp/

You have to remove the default gallery shortcode, and create your own. What I did was copy n paste it, and add in the new class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to put your custom class in the list of classes and then, in your css file, describe the properties associated with that class.

### For example:

#### Your html would be

```
<div id="gallery-2" class="iwmp gallery galleryid-1715 gallery-columns-4 gallery-size-thumbnail">
```

And then let's say you wanted everything in class iwmp to have a red background color and have center alignment you would add the following to your css file:

#### CSS addition:

```
.iwmp {
    background: #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I follow. How, do I get the custom class to appear? This needs to be automatic, not added by myself as such. I was thinking some sort of php function could be added?

Comment: ah, I see.  I don't know offhand of a php solution to this problem, although it can be done very simply with Javascript, even though you don't prefer this.  In JS, it would just be:                       

    document.getElementById('gallery-2').className += ' iwmp';